# How to get checkboxes to behave like radio buttons with using the same name

Tags: jquery, css, forms, pug

[image: Screenshot]

```js
$("input[name='yesFollowup']").on(element_click, function(e){
            if($(this).attr("id") == "yesFollowup"){
                $(".phone_number_yes").show();
            }else{
                $(".phone-number").hide();   
            }
        });

        $('input.followUp:checkbox').on('change', function() {
            $('input.followUp:checkbox').prop({
                'checked': false,
                'disabled': false
            }).removeClass('active');
            $(this).prop({
                'checked': true,
                'disabled': true
            }).addClass('active');
        });
```

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    position: relative;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    vertical-align: -5px;
    color: #fff;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

[type=checkbox], [type=radio] {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

input[type=checkbox]::before {
    content: "✔";
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    right: 0;
    top: -0.3em;
    color: #ffffff;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
.col-sm-2.dealer-item#dealer-item-b.flex-container
    

                    .radio-like-checkboxes(data-validation='required').form-check
                            label(for="yesFollowup")= __('YES')
                            input#yesFollowup(type="checkbox",name='yesFollowup', value="yes", data-value='phone_number_yes')  

                    .radio-like-checkboxes.form-check
                            label(for="noFollowup")= __('NO')
                            input#noFollowup(type="checkbox",name='noFollowup', value="no")
```

At the moment both checkboxes are "checkable" but I would like to have only one checked at a time and to have the check of the other removed when the other is populated.

further, im not sure how to go about ensuring that the "telephone" field is displayed ONLY when the "yes" box is populated and hidden when "no" box is populated.

Comment: Why not just use radio buttons?

Comment: Using the most semantic element greatly improves accessibility and usability overall. If something acts like a button, it should use a `button` element instead of an `a` or a `span` etc. The same goes for form elements. If something acts like an array of radio inputs, it should use radio `input` elements.

Comment: You should use radio itself for such case. also as i see if you are going to submit the form the value is taken from name of input and it doesn't make sense having two check box and checking conditions which is enabled/checked and fetching value based upon it.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use radio buttons that look like checkboxes, using CSS?

The advantage is no code at all, for that... And that exclusiveness behavior already exist with radio buttons... So use it. Nothing stops you from making them look square with a checkmark.

About the the phone number... Use the radio value comparison to toggle the phone input's display.

```js
$("[name='call']").on("click",function(){
    $(".phone").toggle($(this).val()=="yes");
});
```

```css
.container{
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  height:1.8em;
  padding:0.2em;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  position: relative;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  opacity:1;
}

/* The square box */
input[type='radio']:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width:1.3em;
  height:1.3em;
  color: #888;
  border:1.2px solid black;
  border-radius:3px;
  background:#fff;
}

/* The checkmark */
input[type='radio']:checked:after {
  content: "✔";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  right: 0.15em;
  top: -0.2em;
  color: #000;
}

.phone{
  transform: translateY(-0.4em);
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  Yes <input type="radio" name="call" value="yes"> No<input type="radio" name="call" value="no"> <input type="text" class="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Your phone #">
</div>
```

Comment: plus, with this method you don't have to care about the state of the control and event handling

Comment: unfortunately, this solution wont work. I'm working with a backend developer who has requested that we not use any duplicate names. I think it is returning errors when they are doing testing.

Comment: Talk again with your backend developper... I think he talked about `id` rather than `name`. That's how radio inputs work... So that is valid markup.

Comment: I thought the same. I figured that because the IDs and values were different for each that it wouldn't matter. He assures me that it does. :(

Comment: Ok... Then ask you developper why MDN uses the same name for 3 radio inputs in [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)? -- What I say, is this is how a radio input works. The `name` is used to submit the user choice... And only one value associated with the name will be sent, the checked one. -- That is basic HTML.

Comment: I am in total agreement with you. Thank you for your input